# converting from unit to int

Tags: c#, image

I have found this code somewhere to make image square

```
public static Bitmap PadImage(Image originalImage)
{
     int largestDimension = Math.Max(originalImage.Height, originalImage.Width);
     Size squareSize = new Size(largestDimension, largestDimension);
     Bitmap squareImage = new Bitmap(squareSize.Width, squareSize.Height);
     using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(squareImage))
     {
         graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, squareSize.Width, squareSize.Height);
         graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
         graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
         graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

         graphics.DrawImage(originalImage, (squareSize.Width / 2) - (originalImage.Width / 2), (squareSize.Height / 2) - (originalImage.Height / 2), originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height);
     }
     return squareImage;
}
```

but i am getting error on first line

```
int largestDimension = Math.Max(originalImage.Height, originalImage.Width);
```

Error i get is

> cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit' to 'sbyte'

I tried using `Convert.ToByte` but doesn't work.

How do i get rid of this error?

Comment: Compiles for me using `System.Drawing`.. What library are you using?

Comment: @Rob i too use system.drawing